# delete all text between []

Tags: string, batch-file, text, special-characters

I am looking for a batch file that can delete all characters between [] and () and all so delete () [] characters.

example:

Final Fantasy IX (E) (Disc 1) [SLES-02965].bin

need to be

Final Fantasy IX.bin

the files all have different names.

Comment: Did these solutions help you?  Please accept one with a green tick if they did.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" ^|findstr /L "[ (" '
  ) DO (
  CALL :modify "%%a"
 )
)
GOTO :EOF

:modify
SET "name=%~1"
SET "build="
SET "wait="
:loop
IF NOT DEFINED name GOTO done
SET "char=%name:~0,1%"
SET "name=%name:~1%"
IF "%char%"=="%wait%" SET "wait="& GOTO loop
IF DEFINED wait GOTO loop
IF "%char%"=="(" SET "wait=)"& GOTO loop
IF "%char%"=="[" SET "wait=]"& GOTO loop
IF "%char%"==" " IF "%build:~-1%"==" " GOTO loop
SET "build=%build%%char%"
GOTO loop
:done
SET "build=%build: .=.%"
ECHO( REN "%sourcedir%\%~1" "%build%"
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. Assumes `(` and `[` are balanced by `)` and `]`.

Answer (score 0):

this should be faster than Magoo's solution as there's no `goto` and `call` and external command as `FINDSTR` (might fail if file names contains `!` ):

```
@echo off
rem break>"Final Fantasy IX (E) (Disc 1) [SLES-02965].bin"


rem change to the directory you need:
pushd c:\bin_dir
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%f in (*bin) do (
        echo %%~xf
        set "string=%%~nf"
        echo !string!++
        set "string_s=!string:)=^^)" !"
        set "string_s=!string_s:]=]" !"
        set "string_s=!string_s:(= "(!"
        set "string_s=!string_s:[= "[!"

        set "final_string="


        for %%a in (!string_s!) do (
            set "part=%%~a"

            if "!part!" EQU "!part:(=!"  (
                if "!part!" EQU "!part:[=!" (
                    if "!final_string!" NEQ "" (
                        set final_string=!final_string! !part!
                    ) else (
                        set final_string=!part!
                    )
                )
            )

        )
        ren "%%~nf%%~xf" "!final_string!%%~xf"
    )

endlocal

exit /b 0
```